# Converting Images with High DPI and Low Pixels to Low DPI and High Pixels

Tags: resize

I'm currently in the process of making an interactive map. From previous knowledge I learned that it was all about pixel count so that the map could cover a large area. This map needs to cover an area twice the size of the Earth.

My original map is at `35000 x 20000 pixels @ 300 dpi`. Which gives me great zoomability for the interactive map.

However, I was just contacted by an artist that offered to make the map. And they suggested a size of `9000 x 6000 pixels but at 1200 dpi`. Saying that this can be resized up to my original needs without the loss of quality.

My issue here is that I don't understand how that could work. And so, I don't want to start the job and paying for it. Until I'm sure that the end result will be as by my needs.

Comment: Your artist has no clue what they are doing. Pixels and DPI dont work like physical dimensions and DPI. (Pixels are not units)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DPI means absolutely nothing until you need to print it on paper.**

Up to that point, the only thing an image has is **dimensions in pixels**

So your 9,000 edge is barely a quarter the size of your initial 35,000 edge, meaning approx 13 times less detail overall. 7,000 mega-pixel down to a mere 54 mp.

[Presumably you would need to use tiling to be able to handle an image that large, but that's outside the scope of the question.]